# custom HTTP status code with spring and restful webservice

Tags: spring, http, rest, status

I am new to the spring and restful framework. My server hosts 3 restful web services. I have used spring support for the restful web services to implement the server. The client sends JSON request to the server and gets JSON response. Client is based on spring support for the restful. The server returns 200/OK for successful processing, which is default.

What I want is the server to send custom HTTP status code 550 to the client in case there is an issue while processing the request. It should not throw any exception to the client. It should only send 550/an_error_object(as json) back to the client.

How is it possible with the spring support of restful ? I am doing the following on the server side.

HttpServletResponse.setStatus(550)

but, the client side is failing to recognize the status code 550; it throws an exception since org.springframework.http.HttpStatus doesn't have any enum constant '550' defined.

Any suggestions will be great!

Thanks in advance.

Rohit

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't use unregistered status codes. See the [registered status codes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml).

2) That being said, that's a bug in the Spring framework. It should deal properly with extension status codes.

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably going to be fixed in version 4.3 of Spring.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14205